# TagserveLoadGenerator: Problem parsing json from config

Tags: java, json, parsing, apache-kafka, jmeter

I am using jmeter to perform kafka performance testig and using kafkameter for the same. I have used a dummy json file and it was working fine with it but when I am using another json file than it is  throwing error `TagserveLoadGenerator: Problem parsing json from config.` I checked json format too and used different json files which are actually working but not working here.

```
2021-12-29 12:18:43,132 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-12-29 12:18:43,133 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-12-29 12:18:43,133 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JavaSampler: Created class: co.signal.kafkameter.KafkaProducerSampler. Uses tearDownTest: 
2021-12-29 12:18:43,133 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-12-29 12:18:43,176 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-12-29 12:18:43,177 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-12-29 12:18:43,177 ERROR c.s.l.e.TagserveLoadGenerator: Problem parsing json from config:
{
 "name":"sujeet"
}

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.parseSiteConfigs(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:133) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.<init>(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:60) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) [?:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:67) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.iterationStart(LoadGenerator.java:57) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    ... 21 more
2021-12-29 12:18:43,178 ERROR c.s.l.LoadGenerator: Exception initializing Load Generator class: co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:67) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.iterationStart(LoadGenerator.java:57) [kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.parseSiteConfigs(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:133) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.<init>(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:60) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.parseSiteConfigs(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:133) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.<init>(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:60) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    ... 13 more
2021-12-29 12:18:43,178 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-19.0.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:70) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.iterationStart(LoadGenerator.java:57) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:67) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.parseSiteConfigs(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:133) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.<init>(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:60) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:67) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.parseSiteConfigs(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:133) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.example.TagserveLoadGenerator.<init>(TagserveLoadGenerator.java:60) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at co.signal.loadgen.LoadGenerator.createGenerator(LoadGenerator.java:67) ~[kafkameter-0.2.0.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
2021-12-29 12:18:43,178 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-12-29 12:18:43,178 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-12-29 12:18:43,178 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Hello **Sujeet**, Can you please add more information in your question as given info is not enough to understand the problem. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am using jmeter to perform kafka performance testig and using kafkameter for the same. i have used a dummy json file and it was working with it but when i am using another json file than its throwing error "TagserveLoadGenerator: Problem parsing json from config". i have checked json format too and used different json file which are actually working but not working here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a very custom plugin hence we are not able to help.

The `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 10` means that the plugin expects to see `{` and gets some string so double check your JSON payload, there are [online JSON validation tools](https://jsonlint.com/) which can help you to check and/or build the proper [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

You may find [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) easier to use, the comprehensive description and step-by-step instructions can be found in the [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article